# Network sharing error 'net usershare' returned error 1: net: more than one argument supplied

Tags: networking, samba

I am attempting to set up local network sharing on a few folders on my laptop (running 16.04).  Whenever I do, no matter which folder I attempt to share, I get the error message

> 'net usershare' returned error 1: net: more than one argument supplied

I have no clue what this error message means, or how to fix it.  This happens immediately after hitting the <kbd>Create share</kbd> button in the **local network share** menu (with **share this folder** selected).  It doesn't matter what other boxes I check or uncheck in that menu, I always get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried other method besides sharing it via Nautilus? -> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1982137&page=2&s=d26c999eb29cc810e88620192c9bcc56

Comment: I've searched around for terminal-based solutions, but nothing I found resolved the issue, or allowed me to share the folders.  Including editing the smb.conf file to include the folders I am trying to share, re-installing samba, reverting the .conf file to default, and a few other attempts.